# What should be done here to get it solve in reshaping the array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

```
X_test = test_df.drop('Label',axis = 1).values.reshape(test_df.shape[0], 28, 28, 1)
```

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 5630020 into shape (7172,28,28,1)

```
print(test_df.shape) >> (7172, 786)
```

I tried reshaping the numpy array but it seems it is less then 2.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Do you have an idea how could it be that the size of the array is  5630020 while the shape is 7172 * 786 = 5637192?

Comment: Can you provide some more details about the dataframe's total size, dimension, etc.